# Store Data : What is the best way to store data for many entries?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a `Fragment` (but if it is important it can be an `Activity` too) with 8 `EditText`. The entries should be stored but separated. So at the end there should be 8 different lists with the associated entries. The entries are only `Integers`.

What is the best way to store these entries in 8 different lists?

Answer (score 0):

There many possible answers regarding the info you provided. If you have not many items to store, I would go for SharedPreferences API, besides, you can share your data among your code. Other posibility would be to store data in Files, one per list, so 8 in total. And finally, if you are going to share many info, I would suggest to use a SQLite database.

Comment: Each list will have at most 100 entries, so 100 Integers. What would you take ?

Comment: Simplicity: Raw file; Elegancy: SQLite

Comment: Okey thanks. Do you have maybe a website with a good tutorial?

Comment: Check the official docs here, they are self explanatory http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html